# JB Rider can't see newer frameworks

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm not sure how to approach this problem
I installed the .NET 4.7 framework but Rider does not see anything above .NET 3.5

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, It needed at least 5 restarts,
Interesting.